# Finding a word from a text dictionary with given random letters

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

When a person enters a function (e.g. `find_from_dict(letters)`), the function searches a word from dictionary.txt that can be made from the letters that the user has inputted—a word that contains the most letters inputted).

For example, `letters` is input as random typing such as `"BAJPPNLE"` which will then find `"APPLE"` from the dictionary since `"APPLE"` has the most letters from `"BAJPPNLE"`.

```
def find_from_dict(letters):
    n = 0
    y = 0
    x = 0
    dictFile = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("dictionary.txt")]
    listLetters = list(letters)
    final = []

    while True:
        if n < len(dictFile) and len(list(dictFile[n])) <= len(listLetters) and x < len(list(dictFile[n])) and list(dictFile[n])[x] in listLetters:
            x = x + 1
        elif n < len(dictFile) and len(list(dictFile[n])) <= len(listLetters) and x < len(list(dictFile[n])) and list(dictFile[n])[x] not in listLetters:
            x = 0
            n = n + 1
        elif n < len(dictFile) and len(list(dictFile[n])) <= len(listLetters) and x == len(list(dictFile[n])):
            final.append(dictFile[n])
        elif n < len(dictFile) and len(list(dictFile[n])) > len(listLetters):
            n = n + 1
        else:
            print(final)
            break
```

I have this code at the moment, but since my dictionary.txt file is huge and the code is inefficient, it takes forever to go through..

Does anyone have any idea how I could make this code efficient?

Comment: Does the order of the input letters matter? Will EBAJPPNL will still find APPLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed this up by preparing a word index formed of the sorted letters in your  word list.  Then look for sorted combinations of the letters in that index:

for example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

with open("/usr/share/dict/words","r") as wordList:
    words = defaultdict(list)
    for word in wordList.read().upper().split("\n"):
        words[tuple(sorted(word))].append(word)  # index by sorted letters

def findWords(letters):
    for size in range(len(letters),2,-1):  # from large to small (minimum 3 letters)
        for combo in combinations(sorted(letters),size): # combinations of that size
            for word in (w for w in words[combo]):       # matching fords from index
                yield word   # return as you go (iterator)
                             # If you only want one, change this to: return word
```

testing:

```
while True:
    letters = input("Enter letters:")
    if not letters: break
    for word in findWords(letters.upper()):
        stop = input(word)
        if stop: break
    print("")
```

sample output:

```
Enter letters:BAJPPNLE
JELAB
BEJAN
LEBAN
NABLE
PEBAN
PEBAN
ALPEN
NEPAL
PANEL
PENAL
PLANE
ALPEN
NEPAL
PANEL
PENAL
PLANE
APPLE
NAPPE.

Enter letters:EPROING
PERIGON
PIGEON
IGNORE
REGION
PROGNE
OPINER.

Enter letters:
```

if you need a solution without using libraries, you will need to use a recursive approach that does a breadth first traversal of the combination tree:

```
with open("/usr/share/dict/words","r") as wordList:
    words = dict()
    for word in wordList.read().upper().split("\n"):
        words.setdefault(tuple(sorted(word)),list()).append(word)  # index by sorted letters

def findWords(letters,size=None):
    if size == None:
        letters = sorted(letters)
        for size in range(len(letters),2,-1):
            for word in findWords(letters,size): yield word
    elif len(letters) == size:
        for word in words.get(tuple(letters),[]): yield word
    elif len(letters)>size:
        for i in range(len(letters)):
            for word in findWords(letters[:i]+letters[i+1:],size):
                yield word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of "cheat" your way through it by pre-processing the dictionary file.

The idea is: instead of having a list of words, you have a list of groups which is determined by the sorted letters of the words.

For example, something like:

```
"aeegr": [
    "agree",
    "eager",
],
"alps": [
    "alps",
    "laps",
    "pals",
]
```

Then if you wanted to just find the exact match, you could sort the letters from the input and search in the processed file.

But you want the one that matches the most letters, so what you could do is number the letters with prime numbers (I'm only considering lowercase ascii characters), so that `a` is `2`, `b` is `3`, `c` is `5`, `d` is `7` and so on.

Then, you can get a number by multiplying all the letters, so for example for `alps` you'd get `2*37*53*67`.

In your dictionary file you then have the numbers obtained the same way for each word.

Like:

```
262774: [
    "alps",
    "laps",
    "pals",
]
```

You then go through your dictionary and if the initial number divided by the dictionary number has a remainder of 0, that's a possible match.

The maximum number with a remainder of 0 is the one that you want, because that's the one with the most letters present.

Keep in mind that the numbers might get very big very quickly, depending on how many letters you use.

Comment: That's a good general idea, but I think that if a word in the dictionary is long enough, the calculated number is huge. That's not a problem?

Comment: @Ohad That's the point of my last sentence. In theory this should not be a problem in python3 because big numbers are natively supported, but if you consider a 30 letters word composed all of `z` letters, that would be `1347848915332905650585522351309777516867383425202804564353001`, which python can handle